# Problems with getting the number entered by the user during the call

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I have a customer service IVR. At a certain point of this service, I ask the user to choose a license he owns by typing a number on the phone keypad, but when typing a number, the "action" of my response->gather that should call the file itself again passing the number typed by the user does not work and I get the standard Twilio error message. What I don't understand is that it is only happening on this file. I tried debugging several times but I can only log the "else" block of the file, it doesn't even get into the "if" block. Someone could help me, I think it's a detail but I can't find the error.
Here is the code of the whole file to help you understand better:

```
<?php
// Create a route that will handle Twilio webhook requests, sent as an
// HTTP POST to /voice in our application
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'Curl.class.php';
require_once './utils/API.class.php';


API::validateMethod(['POST']);

function logText($title, $content)
{
    $logfile = fopen("./log.txt", "a");
    fwrite($logfile, "\n" . $title);
    fwrite($logfile, "\n" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    fwrite($logfile, "\n" . print_r($content, true));
    fwrite($logfile, "\n" . "-----------------------------------");
    fclose($logfile);
}

function initErrorsLog()
{
    $log_file = "errors.log";
    ini_set("log_errors", true);
    ini_set('error_log', $log_file);
}

use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;

// Use the Twilio PHP SDK to build an XML response
$response = new VoiceResponse();
initErrorsLog();

if (array_key_exists('Digits', $_POST)) {
    // $rs = urldecode($_GET['rs']);
    
    $choosedLicense = $_POST['Digits'];
    $rsDecode = json_decode($rs);
    $rsDecode = json_decode($rsDecode);
    
    logText("rs decoded", $rsDecode);
    logText("choosedLicense", $choosedLicense);
    
    if ($choosedLicense > count($rsDecode->licenses) || $choosedLicense == 0) {
        $rs = urlencode($rs);
        $response->redirect("./invalidLicense.php?rs=$rs");
    }
    
    $token = $rsDecode->auth->token;
    $isBlocked = $rsDecode->licenses[$choosedLicense - 1]->blocked;
    $licenseId = $rsDecode->licenses[$choosedLicense - 1]->id;


    $response->redirect("./waitForFlip.php?licenseId=$licenseId&isBlocked=$isBlocked&token=$token");
    
} else {
    $gather = $response->gather(array('numDigits' => 100, 'timeout' => '4'));
    
    $rs = urldecode($_GET['rs']);
    
    $decode = json_decode($rs);
    $decode = json_decode($decode);
    $count = 0;
    
    foreach ($decode->licenses as $license) {
        $count++;
        $gather->play("https://dl-apis.cadeadodigital.com.br/ura/assets/audios/chooseLicense$count.mp3");
        $gather->play($license->nicknameAudioUrl);
    }

    $rs = urlencode(json_encode($rs));
    $response->redirect("./chooseLicense.php?rs=$rs");
}

// Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $response;
```

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer, but if the code is hitting the `else` block each time, the condition isn't being met. I'd bet that the `Digits` key does not exist. Where are you creating that key?

Comment: I had a quick look through the code and tend to agree with @anthonyjdella. Either the key does not exist in the $_POST array or you need to do a case-insensitive comparison. Secondly, unless you've stripped it out for a shorter example, make sure to validate the $_POST data before using it.